# Where is the smallest park by area?

Tags: where-on-earth, destinations, parks-and-gardens

As I stated in the title, where is the smallest public park (owned by government, local government or a charity such as RHS)?

Comment: according to http://cargocollective.com/brendancormier/Anatomy-of-a-Parkette, a 900 sq m park is only the 165th smallest in Toronto. If anyone can find the list that is 165th on, you could presumably find parks less than 100 sq m

Comment: What defines a park? Because if it just needs to be a patch of grass and maybe a tree, maintained by the government or a charity, I can think of plenty that are not larger than a few square meters.

Comment: @Berend That is the definition of a park so if you have one in mind please give an answer

Comment: I'm never going to beat the current top answer. And if that's the kind of park you were after, that's fine, but somehow I'd expect a park to be just a bit more than a potted tree. Maybe it's time to adjust my narrow views on parks ;-)

Comment: What if a single tree is protected?

Comment: it's a travel Challenge ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is not a travel question

Comment: @Uciebila - I've added the [tag:destinations] tag which makes it on topic.

Comment: @Jeeped I can't imagine just adding a tag makes a question on-topic.

Comment: @Mast As it stands the question has not been closed so draw your assumptions now...

Comment: @Mast - And yet the questioned was not closed, received an even more appropriate tag ([tag:where-on-earth]) and has been upvoted, so win-win.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Technically [Mill Ends Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mill_Ends_Park) in Portland, Oregon, USA. It is a circle 2 feet (0.6 m) across. It was named an official city park in 1976, and is operated by  Portland Parks & Recreation.

[image: Mill Ends Park]

Comment: Bingo! This is really small, and here's its official Portland Parks webpage: https://www.portlandoregon.gov/parks/finder/index.cfm?action=ViewPark&ShowResults=yes&PropertyID=265

Comment: What? Why? Okay, that's just odd.

Comment: This isn't a park according to the definition accepted in comments by the OP: " it just needs to be a patch of grass and maybe a tree".

Comment: But going with that definition this question seems to become essentially [the paradox of the heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox). How many blades of grass make the smallest possible 'patch'? That seems impossible to usefully answer, which makes the question impossible to answer.

Comment: @Spudley This is _Portland_.

Comment: @bdsl quiet! You're encouraging theologians to train angles to plant grass on the head of a pin.

Comment: @Spudley I can think of a few other "parks" in the area that aren't much bigger. I don't get it either. It's especially silly because there's an actual park clearly visible in the picture.

Comment: @Spudley It's likely just to be odd/quirky. Because, you know, it's fun.

Comment: Aren't such micro parks considered well camouflaged pieces of hostile architecture (deny loitering while appearing friendly)?

Comment: Sadly, this park (dating from the 1940s and made official in 1976) was recently vandalized.  However, [this picture](https://www.koin.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2019/12/mill-ends-park-b-12272019.jpg) shows there is indeed grass beneath the (former) tree, @bdsl.  This link also suggests the park has been reforested: https://www.koin.com/local/multnomah-county/tree-cut-down-at-worlds-smallest-park-in-portland/

Comment: 0.6 m across works out to **0.28 m²**, or less than 5 sheets of A4 paper.

Comment: It is nice though - every square foot gets put to good use!

Comment: @rackandboneman, Do you think it's a bad thing to deny loitering *in the middle of the road*?

Comment: @ThePhoton divided on that. If that is the intent, the intent stands no matter how we judge it.

Comment: @rackandboneman, I don't think discouraging people from loitering to keep them from being run over by cars is as bad as discouraging people from loitering to keep from having to see there are poor people in your city. In both cases the immediate intent is to keep people away from some particular area. But the ultimate intent can be very different.

Comment: The operators of the world's actual smallest park (in the UK) have pointed out that this "park" meets none of the defining features of an actual park, dubbing it a ***"glorified flowerpot"***; https://www.prolandscapermagazine.com/uk-city-challenges-worlds-smallest-park-in-portland/

Comment: @Valorum That link actually brings up an interesting point: this park is in the Guiness Book of World records, which explains a lot. It probably means that it was named a park for the sake of being the smallest park. It also means that it's not unlikely a decent amount of money went to the Book for the honor of them recognizing the park. Definitely leaves a sour taste on what is otherwise a beautiful answer for me.

Answer (score 26):

I nominate [Tjoffsans Tivoli](https://www.travelandleisure.com/attractions/amusement-parks/amusement-park-for-mice-malmo-sweden) in [Malmö](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malm%C3%B6), Sweden. It is an amusement park for mice (also known as amousement park) created by [Anonymouse MMX](https://www.facebook.com/AnonymouseMMX/). It's not owned by any government, but it's public and maybe it could be classified as a charity.

[image]

It looks like it covers an area of approximately 1-2 m². It's unclear whether it is still open though.

[image]

Comment: the lights are on, I guess it's open.

Comment: @Jasen I'll believe it when I see any actual mice in attendance...

Comment: Someone should call an inspector on that park. It looks like a death trap to me.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers show non-official parks or "novelty" parks that you cannot actually fit a person into.

Hence, I nominate **Jack Early Park, San Francisco, CA.** It has a flight of stairs leading up to a concrete platform with two benches. You get a nice view over the bay.

I could not find any data on its size, but from having been there myself I estimate the area to not be much more than 25 m² (only counting the platform, not the stairs).

It is hard to find a good picture of the whole park, since it is a small platform. I recommend viewing the [360° view on Google](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jack+Early+Park/@37.8048702,-122.4081675,3a,75y,300h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipOb7iNMzHE-WIx-KU6KMFNpKXABqJxUBaQ6SOlk!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipOb7iNMzHE-WIx-KU6KMFNpKXABqJxUBaQ6SOlk%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi0-ya300-ro-0-fo100!7i7680!8i3840!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x808580fa1229ce0f:0xe53fecc4579befb7!2sJack+Early+Park!8m2!3d37.8048702!4d-122.4081675!3m4!1s0x808580fa1229ce0f:0xe53fecc4579befb7!8m2!3d37.8048702!4d-122.4081675).

[image: Jack Early Park Plaque]

[image: Jack Early Park (c) 2009 Bryan Costales]
(c) 2009 Bryan Costales

Answer (score 8):

Of course, in Japan everything is smaller. This one is 0.25 square metres, complete with bench. However, it's not technically a park, but a road feature, so it doesn't qualify for the Guinness Book of Records:

[image]

See [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E4%B8%80%E5%B0%8F%E3%81%95%E3%81%AA%E5%85%AC%E5%9C%92) or [a local web page](https://j-town.net/tokyo/column/gotochicolumn/292712.html?p=all) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

While not the smallest park in the world, the smallest park in the UK is Prince's Park in Burntwood, Staffordshire.

[image: Photo of Prince's Park, Burntwood]

Photo © Geoff Pick via Wikipedia Commons, CC-BY-SA

[Google Street View link](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@52.6795891,-1.8956011,3a,75y,332.6h,77.87t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sRTumuG18rPYMuNl4aXsqww!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)

It was built in 1863 to commemorate the marriage of the future king Edward VII, and in 2013 was the location for the UK's shortest fun run, with the slowest competitor finishing in a mere 55 seconds: [link](https://www.expressandstar.com/news/2013/05/07/just-55-steps-as-worlds-shortest-fun-run-takes-place-in-burntwood/).

Answer (score 3):

I nominate the small corner lot at North Pacific Avenue and Mission Street, Santa Cruz, California. I concede it is not named as a "Park," and doesn't appear in [the City's list of parks](http://www.cityofsantacruz.com/government/city-departments/parks-recreation/parks-beaches-open-spaces/parks), but it is treated as a park by the City and its residents, and is maintained by the City.

Here's a Street View Picture. The public area is between the blue wall and the street from which the photo was taken:

[image]

Comment: Does it have a sign on it to tell that it is owned or at least managed by a national park or a charity?

Comment: It is owned and managed by a local government (the City of Santa Cruz, a qualifying entity under the terms of the question), which has posted two signs on the property. One is at the right edge of the driveway, a few feet beyond the sidewalk, and appears in the screenshot. There is a second sign, also placed by the City, on the far street border of the property facing Mission Street. Finally, a metal plaque identifying the property as "Scribner Park" (Scribner was a local character, now deceased) is placed on the rock wall visible above on the right.

Comment: By the standard of being treated as a park by a city that maintains it, I nominate the [round-a-bout (traffic circle) at the intersection of Cole Valley Road, Sarehole Road, and the A4040 in Birmingham, England](https://www.google.com/maps/@52.4287592,-1.8560085,3a,60y,39.26h,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sywMo8BoDSpgFhxu9035vsQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656). It has grass, flower beds, a tree, and an official sponsor.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan According to Google Maps measuring tool, the traffic circle center is 22m in diameter, for an area of 380 square meters. Scribner Park is about 25m x 16 m, for an area of 400 square meters. The traffic circle center (everything within the roadway) is thus indeed smaller than Scribner.

Comment: I'm sure there are smaller roundabouts than that one in the UK that are maintained as parks. This one in Belper, Derbyshire is about 19m diameter, and comes with a statue as well as flower beds, sponsors, etc. https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@53.0208585,-1.4846815,3a,75y,29.62h,90t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1suOpBFTtbv1xV9TdU19m5QA!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo2.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DuOpBFTtbv1xV9TdU19m5QA%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dsearch.revgeo_and_fetch.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D96%26h%3D64%26yaw%3D29.61858%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en

Comment: Many traffic circles in Spain have gravel, sand, grass, and/or shrubs and artwork, all maintained by the government.

Comment: Yes, @alephzero. I just quickly picked a small roundabout I happen to know because I grew up near it. The point I was trying to make is that the question may need to define "park" a bit more narrowly.

Comment: The title of the UK's smallest park goes to Prince's Park on the eastern edge of Burntwood, Lichfield. It is a triangle of land at a crossroads, with three trees, a bench and a fence. Using Google Maps I reckon that a triangle of area 197.55m^2 contains it. https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Burntwood/@52.679945,-1.8944182,240m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x4870a062ccc8de27:0x94d0f47df283c6c2!8m2!3d52.679936!4d-1.921781

Answer (score 2):

I bet that the Heemskerk Lunet 10 does make a good chance as the smallest 'national park like' park, as it is a rather small bit of ground owned by Noordhollands Landschap.
[Here is a link to it](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lunet+nr.10/@52.4991785,4.6465998,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c5f0eceb356cef:0x41f05213c0b68622!8m2!3d52.498052!4d4.6496197) on google maps.
And here is a [link to the charity](https://www.landschapnoordholland.nl/natuurgebieden/lunetten) that manages it as well as several others in the area.

I can not find any official information, the charity does not give it on their site. Google maps gives me about 100 x 82 meter, which would give me 8200 m², but that is not very precise.

Comment: Do you know what the area (in km square or miles square) is?

Comment: Looking for the size but it will be in m² rather than km², so small it is.

Comment: That's even better!

Comment: I can not find any official information, the charity does not give it on their site. Google maps gives me about 100 x 82 meter, which would give me 8200 m², but that is not very precise.

Comment: That's close enough, unless someone else can give a more accuratw number

Comment: I read the question as it being a national park, not a city park.

Comment: @Willeke The OP asked about properties owned and maintained by "government, local government, or a charity." In US parlance, "local government" encompasses formal (created by state or local law) entities smaller than state government:; these include cities, counties, and special districts. The City of Santa Cruz is a local government.

Comment: As small parks go, that's rather large.  Just off the top of my head, Codger Park in Colefax is about 720 square meters, Pioneer Plaza in Davenport is about 900 square meters, there's an unnamed park next to the Rosalia library that's 1200 square meters, and I've seen a number of other small-town parks that are about the size of one small shop.

Comment: Singapore, not (so far as I know) having any distinction between national, provincial, and municipal government has some very small "national" parks. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_parks_in_Singapore), Youth Olympic park is only 4,000 square meters, and there are several others under 10,000 square meters. For that matter, any small playground in a publicly owned housing complex might be considered a "national park" there.